# When training a background subtractor, do the frames need to be in temporal sequence?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

When training one of the background subtractors in OpenCV (`BackgroundSubtractorMOG`, `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`, or `BackgroundSubtractorGMG`), do I need to feed the frames in temporal order? Or can the frames be fed in any random order as long as they are of the same scene with the camera at the same position, with similar lighting conditions?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the history parameter and the frame count that you are going to use for training the model. If your frame count is much more than the history parameter (which is the case usually), then you need to set frames in temporal sequence. Or if you are going to train the background model with just a few frames, then I don't think the order is that important. But as I said, it is not the case most of the time and you need to set frames in temporal sequence.

Answer (score -2):

The order would in theory not be important for the initial frames, with the initial frames being the history parameter. However, the moment a new frame comes in, and we have exceeded the history parameter, it is going to replace the first frame that went inside the model. If that, by some random chance, is just the previous frame, and this would happen every time, your model would never properly update.
To clarify this for a bit:
we have frame 1 - 5 labeled A to E, no matter in which order you would enter these, the resulting background would be the same. But, now a 6th frame (F) comes, that means we remove frame 1, place everything back a place, and then add the new frame.
This way 1a 2b 3c 4d 5e would become ->  1b 2c 3d 4e 5f

As you can see, the original frame in place 1 is removed.
This replacing of frames in the end has an effect on how accurate your background model is, replacing old frames with new frames. If you add all the frames in a random order. The background model could potentionally consist of a bunch of old frames, and only a few new ones.

So in short, Just add the frames in a temporal order

I hope this made any sense, If you have any more questions about my answer, just leave a comment.

Comment: This is not a copy of your answer @guneykayim - I read them both and they're actually quite different.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the order of the frames will not matter as long as my `history` parameter is big enough to include all frames, correct?

Comment: In theory, yes.
In practice, not so much.
The moment you start adding more frames than the history parameter (which probably will always be the case) The order will become important, because then the oldest frames are supposed to be removed the first, as described in my answer.

So unless you have a very good reason to NOT enter the frames in temporal order, you're better of adding them in temporal order.